# Details about what happens when entering a function declared in the global scope is missing from ECMAScript Specification v5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, ecma262

The ECMAScript specification goes into detail about what happens when control enters the execution context of a **[function within a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)**.

```
function foo() {
  function bar() {

  }
  bar(); // Control will be given to the bar function.  Details specified by spec
}
```

There also is an explanation of what happens when control [enters global code](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.1).

```
<script>
  // Entering global code!  Details specified by spec
</script>
```

However, there is nothing specifying what happens when entering control for a **function defined in the global code**.

```
<script>
  function foo() {
  }
  foo(); // Calling a function defined in the global environment...not specified by spec
</script>
```

**Edit**:  The reason this is important to me is because I'm curious what the internal [[Scope]] property of the function called by the global code will be.  I assume it will be the lexical environment of the global execution context, but there's nothing that specifies this in the specification.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the sentence *"The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object F [...]"*. It just means that the body of function `F` is executed. It does not make any assumption about where the function was defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you misinterpreted that sentence (from [§10.4.3, *Entering Function Code*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)):

> The following steps are performed when control enters the execution context for function code contained in function object `F`, a caller provided `thisArg`, and a caller provided `argumentsList` […]

It does not mean that the function which is entered must be contained in `F`, but that the *code that is entered* is contained in *the function `F`* (which you are invoking).

The [`[[Call]]` method](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.1) which is used when [calling a function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.2.3) does not distinguish between global/local declared or invoked functions.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Functions declaraed in global code are instantiated during Declaration Binding Instantiation of the global code in step 2 of 10.4.1.

This is done via step 5.c of 10.5 which actually creates each such function object via the first algorithm in section 13. Note that this sets the [[Scope]] of the function to the VariableEnvironment of the current execution context. The current execution context was set by step 1 of 10.4.1 (via 10.4.1.1) to the Global Environment.